# create new columns from xml value in hive

Tags: sql, hive, hql, impala

I have a column `desc_txt` in my table and its contents are quite similar to that of xml like shown below-

```
desc_txt 
-----------
<td><strong>Criticality</strong></td><td>High</td></tr><td><strong>Country</strong></td><td>India</td></tr><tr><td><strong>City</strong></td><td>Indore</td>
```

Requirement is to have a new table/view created from this table having additional columns like `Criticality`, `Country`, `City` along with the column values like `High`, `India`, `Indore`, respectively.
How can this be achieved in Hive/Impala?

Comment: What have you tried and what were the issues?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in two steps. I assumed you have only four columns to pull.

1. Load the data as is in a table. Put everything in a column.
2. Then use this below SQL to split the data multiple columns. I assumed 4 columns, you can increase as per your requirement.

`with t as  (
 SELECT rtrim(ltrim(
 regexp_replace( replace( trim(
  regexp_replace(
 regexp_replace("<td><strong>Criticality</strong></td><td>High</td></tr><td><strong>Country</strong></td><td>India</td></tr><tr><td><strong>City</strong></td><td>Indore</td>","</?[^>]*>",",")
 ,',,',',') ), ' ,', ',' ), '(,){2,}', ','),','),',')
 str)
select split_part(str, ',', 1) as first_col,
split_part(str, ',', 2) as second_col,
split_part(str, ',', 3) as third_col,
split_part(str, ',', 4) as fourth_col
from t`

The query is tricky - first it replaces all tags with comma in them, then it replaces multiple commas with single comma, then it removes comma from start and end of the string. split function then splits whole string based on comma and create individual columns. 
HTH...

Comment: Thanks Koushik.....here the requirement is to have Criticality as a column and the column value should be High similarly, Country as the column and its value as India.....All these are in the same desc_txt column